# How to sort on one of several parameters in a struct

Tags: c#

What im trying to do is to sort each struct(Säljare1 - Säljare6) in order of the input in the last parameter (Niva), so if Salesman1&2(Säljare1&2) has reached Niva(Level) sales of 100 samples, then both Säljare1&2 stats will be displayed followed by "this many Salesman have reached Niva 2.

So, how do i instruct the program to choose sorting on parameter Niva?

```
public struct Säljare6
{
    public String Namn;
    public String Personnummer;
    private String Distrikt;
    private int AntalArtiklar;
    private int Niva;



    public string NAMN
    {
        get { return Namn; }
        set { Namn = value; }
    }
    public string PERSONNUMMER
    {
        get { return this.Personnummer; }
        set { this.Personnummer = value; }
    }
    public String DISTRIKT
    {
        get { return Distrikt; }
        set { Distrikt = value; }
    }
    public int ANTALARTIKLAR
    {
        get { return AntalArtiklar; }
        set { AntalArtiklar = value; }
    }
    public int NIVA
    {
        get { return Niva; }
        set { Niva = value; }
    }

    public Säljare6(string Namn6, string Personnummer6, string Distrikt6, int AntalArtiklar6, int Niva6)
    {


        this.Namn = Namn6;
        this.Personnummer = Personnummer6;
        this.Distrikt = Distrikt6;
        this.AntalArtiklar = AntalArtiklar6;
        this.Niva = Niva6;
    }


    public void SkrivUtInfo()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3} && Niva = {4}", this.Namn, this.Personnummer, this.Distrikt, this.AntalArtiklar, this.Niva);
    }
}



class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
        Säljare1 S1 = new Säljare1(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för nästa säljare (1,Namn (enter), 2,persnr (enter), 3,Distrikt(enter), 4,AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
        Säljare2 S2 = new Säljare2(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för nästa säljare (1,Namn (enter), 2,persnr (enter), 3,Distrikt(enter), 4,AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
        Säljare3 S3 = new Säljare3(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för nästa säljare (1,Namn (enter), 2,persnr (enter), 3,Distrikt(enter), 4,AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
        Säljare4 S4 = new Säljare4(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för nästa säljare (1,Namn (enter), 2,persnr (enter), 3,Distrikt(enter), 4,AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
        Säljare5 S5 = new Säljare5(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för nästa säljare (1,Namn (enter), 2,persnr (enter), 3,Distrikt(enter), 4,AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
        Säljare6 S6 = new Säljare6(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        S1.SkrivUtInfo();
        S2.SkrivUtInfo();
        S3.SkrivUtInfo();
        S4.SkrivUtInfo();
        S5.SkrivUtInfo();
        S6.SkrivUtInfo();
```

Comment: This should be a class not a struct. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx): _"Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the type are **small and commonly short-lived** or are commonly embedded in other objects.

Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:

It logically **represents a single value, similar to primitive types** (integer, double, and so on).
It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
**It is immutable**.
It will not have to be boxed frequently."_

Comment: What does `Säljare1`, `Säljare2` etc. look like? What do they have in common? It looks from the code like they are going to have the same structure, so why are they different types?

Comment: If you want to sort your objects then you're going to want to put them into a collection of some kind, such as a `List<Säljare6>`.

Comment: If i change the struct into a class, will i be able to use the rest of the code or start from scratch?                                                               Säljare1 represents a person, im sorry im new at this and doesnt really understand i created several Säljare structs because i thought it would make it possible to compare them against eachother.

Comment: It looks like you have 6 sales persons and you defined 6 separate yet identical `struct` types, one for each expected instance. That is the *exact opposite* of how it should be! **Definitions** for equal structures or objects are done once, and then used as often as needed, which we call instantiating. Just imagine you are dealing with 1000s of sales persons with that approach... the horror!

Comment: Okey I understand, However even when i change into one struct that i use for all salespersons, I will still have the problem of sorting them according to their amount of sales. Can this be solved by using List<>?

Comment: A `struct` (and for that matter a `class`) creates a type. If you have 6 things of the same type you only need one `struct` and then 6 instances of it `Säljare s1 = new Säljare(…); Säljare s2 = new Säljare(…);` etc. You can then also have a list or array of `Säljare` so you can have any number of sales people, and sorting becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, it looks like you created several structs of the same structure.

Here is a sample class, which implements the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface that allows you to use, for example, the [List.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
public class MyObject : IComparable
{
    public MyObject(string name, int level)
    {
        Name = name;
        Level = level;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Level { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}, level {Level}";
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var myObj = obj as MyObject;
        if (myObj == null) return -1;

        int compare = Level.CompareTo(myObj.Level);
        if (compare != 0) return compare;

        // objects are in the same order
        // order by name
        return string.Compare(Name, myObj.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Try it:

```
public void TestSort()
{
    var list = new List<MyObject>();
    list.Add(new MyObject("e", 1));
    list.Add(new MyObject("d", 4));
    list.Add(new MyObject("b", 2));
    list.Add(new MyObject("a", 1));
    list.Add(new MyObject("c", 3));
    list.Add(new MyObject("a", 4));

    Debug.WriteLine("unsorted");
    list.ForEach(obj => Debug.WriteLine(obj));
    list.Sort();
    Debug.WriteLine("sorted");
    list.ForEach(obj => Debug.WriteLine(obj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your code that you have declared a separate class for each of your salesmen. You should not do this as a class describes/defines a *type of thing* **not** a *specific thing*.

You can use a List<> for this. The code below shows two ways to do it, one using only for and foreach, and another uses 'LINQ' with lambdas (the first example) which probably a little too advanced for beginners but it's my opinion that it is so useful know that even beginners should know what is possible to do with it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Säljare> salesmen = new List<Säljare>();

        var nivaMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            nivaMax = Math.Max(nivaMax , saljare.NIVA);
            salesmen.Add(saljare);
        }

        //We're telling the GroupBy method what we want to 'group by'
        //this is the 'LINQ' part.
        foreach (var nivaGruppe in salesmen.GroupBy(x => x.NIVA))
        {
            var groupNivå = nivaGruppe.Key;
            var howManyInGroup = nivaGruppe.Count();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", howManyInGroup, groupNivå);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

        for (int level = 0; level < nivaMax; level++)
        {
            var salesmenAtLevel = 0;
            foreach (Säljare saljare in salesmen)
            {
                if (saljare.NIVA == level)
                {
                    salesmenAtLevel++;
                }
            }
            if (salesmenAtLevel > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel, level);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

This is one way you could compute level from article count.

```
public int NIVA
{
    get 
    { 
        return System.Math.Ceiling(AntalArtiklar / 100.0);
    }
}
```

Another way:

```
public int NIVA
{ 
    get
    {
        if( this.AntalArtiklar <= 49) return 1;
        if( this.AntalArtiklar <= 99) return 2;
        if( this.AntalArtiklar <= 199) return 3;
        if( this.AntalArtiklar >  199) return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if i want to have constant levels of 1 = 0-100 sales, 2 = 100-200 sales. for example Name: Roger Persnr: 923452 Distrikt: Berlin Antal: 200. Followed by 1 salesman have reached level 2(200+). Is it easiest to use arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what mean by "constant" levels. Do you mean that the number of sales should define which level the salesman is at? In that case you should not require input for Niva but rather compute it in the 'get' part of your Niva property.

Arrays and Lists are similar. The important difference between the two is that arrays have a fixed size when you create them (real world analogy = bookshelf, some shelves can be 'empty') while lists can grow and shrink as items are added/removed (real world analogy = paperclips linked together in a chain, no 'empty' places).

Comment: Im trying to make the Niva property get value into <100, however it says that it a invalid expression. If im not able to use logic how is it possible to set a range of value for example 0-100?

Comment: @konto123 I've updated the answer with what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Its not working :/  public int NIVA(object obj)
            {

                if (AntalArtiklar <= 49)
                { Niva1 = 1; }
                   if (this.AntalArtiklar(Säljare) <= 99)
                     { Niva1 = 2;}
                     if (this.AntalArtiklar <=199)
                     { Niva1 = 3;}
                     if( this.AntalArtiklar > 199)
                     {Niva1 = 4;}
            }

Comment: I hope that explains what im trying to do. I really appreciate your help. Just cant seem to get it working.

Comment: The  code you wrote won't compile, it expects you to return a value which it doesn't do. Where is this Niva1 coming from? Change your code so that instead of "Niva1 = 1" you have "return 1". I have updated the answer.